# Postgresql запрос через Idea

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, boot

Создаю рест сервер, и при запросе компиляции возникает ошибка, но сервер запускается

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ������: ������ ���������� (��������� ���������: "user")
```

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/messages}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:****}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:****}
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
```

Comment: Что то мне говорит что сервер не может подключиться к базе данных. Посмотрите внимательно на usename password databasename и host

Comment: Что то мне говорит что сервер не может подключиться к базе данных. Посмотрите внимательно на usename password databasename и host